# Embedding ng2 tooltip in ng2 smart table

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap, ng2-smart-table

I have already installed `ng2-tooltip-directive` and imported in `app.module.ts`.

I am trying to add a tooltip to ng2 smart table cell for overflow but `valuePrepareFunction()` is only adding the `class` nodelist. I am expecting it to add all the tooltip properties as well. Here is the snippet:

```
  NODEBLIST: {
    title: 'eNodeB',
    type: 'html',
    valuePrepareFunction: (data) => '<div class="nodelist" ngbTooltip="You see, I show up on click!" triggers="click:blur">' + data + '</div>',
    // type: 'string',
  },
```

and when I inspect the elements it only shows the class was added:

```
<div class="nodelist">KSL05836 KSL09836R</div>
```

any insight on how to get the tooltip properties to be added would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `valuePrepareFunction` will not bind any Angular Component or Directive.

Comment: Okay - how do you add a tooltip to a table cell in a ng2 smart table?

Comment: Added the answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular Binding is not possible within the function `valuePrepareFunction` so better you drop the plan of html and use the custom component option instead.

```
 NODEBLIST: {
    title: 'eNodeB',
    type: 'custom',
    renderComponent: TooltipComponent
  },
```

### component

Its just the sample code, you can modify as per your requirement.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'tooltip-view',
      template: `
        <div class="nodelist" ngbTooltip="You see, I show up on click!" triggers="click:blur">{{rowData.eNodeB}}</div>
      `,
    })

    @NgModule()
    export class TooltipComponent{
      renderValue: string;

      @Input() value: string | number;
      @Input() rowData: any;

    }
```

entryComponents

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, Ng2SmartTableModule ],
  entryComponents: [CustomComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> Note : Since the code is written in the stackoverflow editor directly, there could be typo or syntactical error. Please correct yourself.

Comment: I am trying to implement this but now the table data is empty.

Comment: If you are facing issue in implementation of custom component. You can refer this ex https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-smart-table-column-cal-m9nxpg

Comment: Thank you I will check it out. This is the error I am getting in the console:
ERROR Error: No component factory found for TooltipComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Comment: just add `TooltipComponent` in `entryComponents` of Module.

Comment: Example added in answer. Just make sure you are declaring it for your module.

Comment: okay very close now! instead of customer message how do I show the table data from the cell? right now it is displaying: "You see, I show up on click!" upon clicking the table cell

Comment: you have `rowData` in the custom component.

Comment: row how do I access the 4th table cell in that row?

Comment: its property name in your from json array ex `rowData.title`

Comment: In your case I guess it is `eNodeB`. So you can use as `rowData.eNodeB`

Comment: hmm and I putting rowData.eNodeB in the correct spot?

  @Input() value: string | number;
  @Input() rowData.eNodeB: any;

Comment: It must be in html. I have updated the answer with `{{rowData.eNodeB}}`

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it :)